# Web3 client can't write to contract in Flutter app using WalletConnect for credendtial

Tags: flutter, ethereum, wallet-connect, web3dart

I used web3dart with flutter with Ganache and Truffle to run my Solidity contract, the contract is being read fine by my Flutter app but when I run functions that write to the contract it doesn't work (can't write to the contract from the app). I saw on the web3dart package it says you should use .sendTransaction() instead of .call() when running a function that writes to the contract

[image: 1]

for the credential, I used WalletConnect I used the WalletConnectEthereumCredentials class that was written in the package example source code [here](https://github.com/RootSoft/walletconnect-dart-sdk/tree/master/example/mobile)

The transaction is successful from MetaMask wallet Address to the contract address(traceable with EtherScan), but still, contract data remains unchanged.

Solidity Code:

```
   function update(string memory newMessage) public {
        message = newMessage;
}
```

Flutter Code:

```
      final cred = WalletConnectEthereumCredentials(provider: provider);
      try {
        var transactionId = await _web3client.sendTransaction(
            cred,
            Transaction.callContract(
              contract: _deployedContract,
              function: _updateFunction,
              parameters: ["NEW_MESSAGE"],
              from: EthereumAddress.fromHex(
                  cred.provider.connector.session.accounts[0]),
            ),
            chainId: 4);
```

You can see what's on `WalletConnectEthereumCredentials` and `WalletConnectEthereumCredentials` on the walletConnect [repository](https://github.com/RootSoft/walletconnect-dart-sdk/tree/master/example/mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Just deploy the contract instead of running it locally on your machine.

I was basically trying to make a transaction to a contract that is running locally on Ganache. So I deployed the contract on [truffle](https://docs.infura.io/infura/tutorials/ethereum/deploy-a-contract-using-truffle), this solved the issue and I can fully interact with the contract using my app.